# How do I get a reference to the window object within an Angular 5 Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular version 5 and making reference to the following article:

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

I am trying to access both `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onfocus`

I have followed through with this article and created a new service but now within my actual component where I need to access `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onfocus`, I am not sure how to incorporate the following functions:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  userWantsToLeave = true;
  console.log("onbeforeunload: ",userWantsToLeave);
};

window.onfocus = function() {
  if(userWantsToLeave) {
    userWantsToLeave = false;
    console.log("onfocus: ",userWantsToLeave);
  }
}
```

Where within my component can I achieve the above two functions at the same time, using the article attached?

I just need to be able to access these two window functions within my component.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HostListener` like this.

```
import { Component , HostListener } from '@angular/core';
export class AppComponent {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    doSomething($event) {
        /// code
    }

    @HostListener('window:focus', ['$event'])
    dofocus($event) {
        /// code
    }
    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help but unfortunately these hostlisteneners don't seem to be triggered within Firefox when I receive the Leave Page/Stay on Page modal dialog and press the Stay on Page button. Any ideas pls?